# median of cells if conditions - openoffice-calc

Tags: median, openoffice-calc, calc

Is there a function in openoffice-calc like `AVERAGEIFS` for the median?

If not, is there a function that gives the list of all the cells satisfaying a condition, so that I can apply the median to that list?

I need to convert this formula:

`=AVERAGEIFS(J$22:J$720,D$22:D$720,">=0",D$22:D$720,"<2")`

into something like:

`=MEDIANIFS(J$22:J$720,D$22:D$720,">=0",D$22:D$720,"<2")`

Comment: OpenOffice.org is outdated. Are you asking about LibreOffice or Apache OpenOffice? It would be good to correct the title and tags to reflect that, even though it may not make a difference for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(D22:D720<0;"<no value";IF(D22:D720>2;"<no value";J22:J720)))
```

This will find the median for an odd number of values, or the mean if there is an even number.

Adapted from https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/median-with-condition-in-calc/38522.